# connecting solar panels cells with copper adhesive foil

Tags: solar-cell

i have purchased some cheap solar panel cells , as am bad it soldering , so i was wondering that Is it good practice to connect solar panels with copper adhesive foil or bad , because with copper adhesive foil its easy to connect solar panels rather using soldering gun and bus wire.

Comment: Without going into details you can already know the answer if it is good practise: What would be easier? Why does the rest of the world the hard way? So, you either did a brilliant invention or there is a reason the rest of the world does it differently.

Comment: Some reasons: foil tears easily compared to bus wire, glue can come loose more easily than solder joint, resistance etc

Comment: I think you're forgetting that the **adhesive** in the adhesive foil isn't electrically conductive. So if you stick the foil on a solar panel contact, that does not mean that there is a good electrical contact. Perhaps that's the reason why no one does this. **All** grand masters of soldering were poor at soldering one day. They improved their skills by **practicing**. You can do the same.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - Hi, I'm not going to get involved with the usage in the question, but regarding: "*I think you're forgetting that the adhesive in the adhesive foil isn't electrically conductive*" I used to think that too (I think this used to be the only type). Then I discovered there are now two different types of adhesive available on copper tape - the expected non-conductive, and another *conductive* adhesive type. Here's a datasheet for a [3M copper tape with conductive adhesive](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/1/1181-45855.pdf) as an example. So such tape does exist... HTH.

Comment: @SamGibson OK, 5 mohm, not bad. The footnote does say *Method 3 07 maintained at 5 psi (3,4 N/cm2 ) measured over 1 in2  surface area*, the "maintained" has me wondering if there is constant pressure applied to press the tape to the conducting surface. Without that pressure, it is anyone's guess what the contact resistance will be. Note also that: *Conductive particles in the adhesive provide the electrical path between the application substrate and the foil backing* So it isn't the adhesive itself that provides the conductivity.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - I've no disagreements with any of your points, except that stating the adhesive isn't conductive is a bit of a nitpick :-)  The adhesive *layer* (with its particles) is conductive, allowing 3M to describe it as "Conductive acrylic adhesive". The concern about pressure is one of several reasons why I'm not replying to the question. I've only used this tape in situations where there was such pressure.

Comment: thanks everyone for suggestions :) so that mean i should try to solder them , so i have order these solar cells it comes with wire and flux pen : https://www.aliexpress.com/item/100W-DIY-Solar-Panel-Kit-40Pcs-Monocrystall-Solar-Cell-5x5-With-20M-Tabbing-Wire-2M-Busbar/32808793841.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4bc94c4dwZt7Tt

Comment: and i have this soldering gun with which i have hard time solder small wires not sure its suitable for solar bus wires or not , 60w  : https://www.aliexpress.com/item/200-450-Temperature-60W-AC-220V-Electric-Soldering-Iron-5PC-Soldering-Iron-Tips-For-SMT-SMD/32411734773.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.352d748cC2YZ9f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_6,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=66b13bb6-ede0-4fd0-bb5b-393a402ef471-1&algo_pvid=66b13bb6-ede0-4fd0-bb5b-393a402ef471

Comment: so do you guys think i should buy new soldering gun for these bus wires or not because  they seems to be big so i guess i will power full soldering gun to wire them , so can u guys suggest me some good soldering gun which is good for all purpose small and big wires likes these solar panel bus wires